# cypress: pass array as command line argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, cypress

I am working on [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) for automatic testing. I want to pass list of variables through the command prompt.

For ex:

```
$(npm bin)/cypress run --env pages=page1,page2 --spec 'cypress/integration/atests/test.spec.js'
```

But it fails. Error is thrown as `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at piperToCommas`.

Can anyone tell/guide me, how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**

I think you could pass your variables with a JSON and then you can access them as a normal javascript object.

Example:

```
$(npm bin)/cypress run --env token='{"a":"5", "b":{"c":"x"}}'
```

Now in your spec, if you call `Cypress.env('token')` you'll get this object as output.

[image]

If you want the enviroment variable as an array, you could pass it this way:

```
$(npm bin)/cypress run --env token='["a", "b"]'
```

Output:

[image]

---

If I understood the question correctly, you should pass the variables in the form:

`cypress run --env name1=value1,name2=value2,...`

Example:

```
cypress run --env host=kevin.dev.local,api_server=http://localhost:8888/api/v1
```

This will create two environment variables, `host` with value `kevin.dev.local` and `api_server` with value `http://localhost:8888/api/v1`.

Comment: Sorry. I want to pass variables like `names=name1,names2`. So that I can access `names` array in the application.

Comment: @Pradeepb sorry, I misunderstood your question and edited my answer.